# Why does people use wp_register_style and wp_enque_style? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, include, styles

I see [wp_register_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/) and [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) everywhere whenver I check other Wordpress plugin files.

```
public function cmc_shortcode_style() {
  wp_register_style( 'cmc-shortcodes-style', plugins_url( 'assets/css/cmc-shortcodes.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'cmc-shortcodes-style' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'cmc_shortcode_style' ) );
```

I also read the Wordpress document and found out that it works similar as include or require. 
Then why don't they just use include?

```
include (ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/cmc/assets/css/cmc-shortcodes.css');
```

Hmm...There would be a definite reason 'cause everyone is using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions are used for several reasons:

- Dequeuing - Whatever is enqueued by someone can also be dequeued by someone later
- Bundling - There are many plugins that take all of the scripts and styles that are enqueued and spit out optimized versions
- CDN - Similar to the previous, there are plugins that are able to offload enqueue assets to a CDN
- Inlining - Same as the previous again, some plugins might inline your resource instead of having the browser manually request it
- Security - A plugin could use this information to apply [SRI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) to the HTML
- Dependencies - The dependency option allows you to further say "if you use this, also include these first".

  - The entire jQuery system is a great example. If you write code that uses jQuery, you can enqueue it with `jquery` as a dependency and WordPress will make sure your JS is loaded later. Similarly, if you need Masonry, you can use `jquery-masonry` and both jQuery and Masonry will be loaded in the correct order
- Cache busting - By using the version option you can specify an argument that will be appended to the query string which allows for efficient client-side caching with a simple override

That's just off the top of my head, probably a bunch more